# RSA Key Pair Generation Command EE9001 gives Error 03

Tags: cryptography, hsm

I'm using SafeNet HSM and trying to execute Command EE9001 for generating RSA Key Pair:

```
Request to HSM:
    \01\01\22\00\00\13\EE\90\01\12\17\18\46\44\24\58\73\00\00\02\08\00\01\00\01
```

Where,

\01\01\22\00      **is Header**
\00\13            **is Message Length**
\EE\90\01         **is Function Code**
\12\17\18\46\44\24\58\73      **is Command Identifier**
\00   is **Function Modifier**
\00\02   **is KeyType**
\08\00 **is Modulus size**
\01\00\01 **is Public Exponent**

```
Response from HSM:
     01 01 22 00 00 0C EE 90 01 12 17 18 46 44 24 58 73 03
```

Where the last 2 characters represent the error code i-e 03 which means: *Incorrect message length*. Seems like the error code is miss leading as the length in hex is correct in the request command.

**Hints:** In the document its written:
1. Ensure that the modulus is compatible with the specified public exponent. (I don't know what compatibility are they talking about!)

2. The Var length of 'Public Exponent' and 'User Data' might make it difficult to segregate both (to figure out their actual length).

Following is the Command from Manual ('h' represents hex value) :

[image]

I have executed another Command '9B' for generating CVV, and that executed successfully. But in that command there was no Var length Request Content.

Help is appreciated a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I got it! One of my friends assisted me with it.

**Request:**

```
\01\01\22\00\00\15\EE\90\01\12\17\18\46\44\24\58\73\00\00\02\01\00\03\01\00\01\00
```

*Where,*

\01\01\22\00 **is Header**
\00\15 **is Message length**
\EE\90\01 **is Function Code**
\12\17\18\46\44\24\58\73 **is Command Identifier**
\00 is **Function Modifier**
\00\02 **is KeyType**
\01\00 **is Modulus size**
03\01\00\01 **is Public Exponent**  (Here 03 represent the length of Var field)
00\ **is User Data**

The response was successful!